# How to restart Bluetooth service from command line

Tags: macos, bluetooth, daemons

On Linux, if one wishes to restart the Bluetooth service, they simply launch a terminal and issue the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

What is the equivalent on Mac OS X?  I would like to restart my Bluetooth without having to restart the entire computer.

I am using `Yosemite`.

Update:  Of the various command line options provided by Testing below the only one that seemed to work was the last, which is this:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
```

Update 2: The above command no longer works and I wonder if it ever did.  The first time I tried it it might have been something else that restarted my bluetooth services.  The only thing that will work for me is a restart of the entire machine every morning.

Comment: If installing another app is an option, you might check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/ralph-hm/a65840c4f5e439b90170d735a89a863f

Comment: I removed the com.apple.Bluetooth.plist from /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/ or /Library/Preferences/ and restarted > fixed. the terminal commands below did not work for me - but of course you can make a terminal command that removes this file and then restarts your mac :)

Comment: For Big Sur (macOS 11.6) this is what worked for me: `sudo launchctl stop com.apple.bluetoothd; sudo launchctl start com.apple.bluetoothd`

Answer (score 64):

On High Sierra, none of the command line options worked for me.  I was able to plug in a wired USB mouse and use the Shift + Option with Debug/Rest solution.

I tried the blueutil solution on my High Sierra, and it worked like a charm.  I regularly have Bluetooth on my 2015 MBPR with an Apple Magic Mouse hose up, and have to restart. Yeah, I could open the lid and use the track pad, but it's on the other side of the wall from my desk space.

You can install **blueutil** using Homebrew:

```
brew install blueutil
```

Or you can compile and install it by hand using:

```
cd ~/tmp/
git clone https://github.com/toy/blueutil.git
cd blueutil
make
make test 
cp blueutil ~/bin/
```

Now run:

```
blueutil -p 0 && sleep 1 && blueutil -p 1
```

Comment: The command didn't work for me. I had to run `blueutil -p 0 && sleep 1 && blueutil -p 1` Also `~/bin` resulted in location does not exist message. Required the full location which was `/usr/local/bin`. Worked perfectly then for me. Thanks.

Comment: Running test seems successful, but always starts with `./test: line 3: read: 0.001: invalid timeout specification`
Then when I run `blueutil off && sleep 1 && blueutil on` I get `-bash: blueutil: command not found`

Comment: Never heard of this util, saved my bacon.  `v10.14.5` for me and it works great.  Installs with macports also, if you don't love brew either.

Comment: This command may be useful, but it doesn't actually restart the Bluetooth service. You can verify this by running `ps aux |grep -i blue` . The answer by Yusuf does restart the service: `sudo pkill bluetoothd`

Comment: @BryanRoach - I never claimed it restarted the bluetooth services.

Comment: @sygibson - The original question is "How to restart Bluetooth service from command line", so I thought I should at least point it out.

Comment: I'm on Ventura 13.4.1 and this worked great for me. I created a custom bash command to hold this, something like "restart_bluetooth", so I don't have to remember all the blueutil stuff.

Answer (score 58):

```
sudo pkill bluetoothd
```

**NOTE:** Works for me on macOS High Sierra

My Logitech MX Anywhere mouse does not work after sleeping sometimes. As I've read it's not because of mouse, it's a macOS Smart Bluetooth bug. But my Apple keyboard always works, never has this issue.

Sometimes I wake up my computer, the Apple keyboard is working but the Logitech mouse is not working. So without the mouse I cannot restart Bluetooth from the system (I could close the lid but my keyboard also goes away, so cannot restart it again).

I started to use this command from the terminal, it stops the service but when the service stops it automatically restarts it self. And my mouse starts working within a second!

Comment: Oh nice, this fix my laggy magic mouse

Comment: works like a charm in MacOS Monterrey 12.6

Comment: You may have a related Bluetooth service running called BlueTool. To restart everything, run `ps aux |grep -i blue` to get the PID for BlueTool. Kill BlueTool with `sudo kill -9 <PID>` . Now if you run `sudo pkill bluetoothd` it will restart both services.

Comment: Worked for me on Monterey 12.6

Comment: This fixes the MX Master 3S working-choppy issue with MacBook Pro M1 Max.

Comment: Simple, quick and no need to install any third party packages. Had problems connecting to AirPods and bluetooth speaker, and this fixed it without having to restart. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

On El Capitan, it's kind of tricky because it doesn't allow you to unload system services. However, a brute-force method is:
`sudo pkill blued`
'blued' is the OS X bluetooth daemon, and it will automatically restart when terminated (at least when I tested it on my El Capitan machine). Other related daemons are: com.apple.bluetoothReporter, com.apple.IOBluetoothUSBDFU, and com.apple.bluetoothaudiod (you can look at the daemons running using `sudo launchctl list`)

You can also try:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.blued
sudo launchctl start com.apple.blued
```

If you have an older OS X version, it's cleaner:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```

or

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
```

Comment: I tried all three of the commands you suggested and none of them would kill and/or restart bluetooth.  I say this because I was still able to use my bluetooth mouse and keyboard after issuing the 'kill' version of each of the commands.  Any other ideas?  I am on Yosemite at the moment.

Comment: @zeeple: you are right. All the command provided by @Testing will cause an automatic restart of killed daemons because they are configured in this way by `launchd` (which command interface is `launchctl`).

Comment: This morning none of these commands are working to get my bluetooth working again.  The only thing that would work was a reboot of the OS.

Comment: On El Capitan the `sudo launchctl stop com.apple.blued` command does indeed auto-restart the daemon without the start command. The older commands don't do anything on El Capitan so unfortunately I don't have much more insight (I upgraded my last Yosemite machine just a couple weeks ago).

Comment: Sadly, I work for a giant company with a backwards IT dept.  They will not allow upgrading to anything beyond Yosemite.  None of the commands above work for me at all.  Restarting the entire machine every morning is the only thing that will work.

Comment: kextunload & load worked for me on Yosemite

Comment: 'sudo pkill blued' did not work for me on El Capitan.

Comment: sudo pkill blued fix my earphones not being seen, thanks

Answer (score 23):

One thing to mention is the daemon name **blued** (at least until macOS 10.11 El Capitan), has been changed to **bluetoothd**.

So based on the version of the macOS, you need to change the daemon name in the below command(s).

Another thing to note is that, unload then load the daemon's plist(instead of stop then start or sending HUP signal) may not work due to the SIP(System Integrity Protection) introduced in El Capitan.
But it should work when you disabled the SIP or on macOS before El Capitan.

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```

Even in the SIP environment(after El Capitan) you can simply **launchctl stop** then **launchctl start** the daemon.

```
$ sudo launchctl stop com.apple.bluetoothd # or blued based on macOS version
$ sudo launchctl start com.apple.bluetoothd
```

In case you just want the status(on|off) of bluetooth to be changed, not wanting the daemon to actually restart, you can do the following,

```
# Let bluetooth be on 
$ sudo defaults write 
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth ControllerPowerState -int 1

# let bluetooth be off 
$ sudo defaults write 
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth ControllerPowerState -int 0

# Then reload the daemon
$ sudo killall -HUP bluetoothd # or blued based on macOS version
# On a macOS system which has proctools installed, you can replace `killall` to `pkill`
```

Blueutil is cool stuff, but it is using some **private** APIs of IOBluetooth.framework, so it may not work on the future version of macOS.

Answer (score 10):

For my Macbook Pro 2017 with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, I restart bluetooth using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo launchctl stop com.apple.bluetoothd
sudo launchctl start com.apple.bluetoothd
```

Comment: Thanks! This also works on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 5):

This 3rd party command line tool seems to work all the way up to High Sierra, abstracting away the differences between OSX versions: https://github.com/toy/blueutil

Comment: works for me on 10.13 `blueutil off && blueutil s && blueutil on`
plus it can be installed via brew `brew install blueutil`

Answer (score 2):

Found this [page](https://gist.github.com/nicolasembleton/afc19940da26716f8e90) on GitHub Gist with commands that worked for me (I am running Yosemite v. 10.10.5). You can simply type the following in the terminal to restart the bluetooth daemon without restarting:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport

sudo kextload -b com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport
```

[bluetooth](/questions/tagged/bluetooth) [daemon](/questions/tagged/daemon)

Answer (score 2):

I am running Yosemite v10.10.5 and none of the other comments / gists worked for me at all. The only steps that I managed to figure out to take back to life the bluetooth driver was:

1. Execute sudo `kextunload -b
   com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport` in the
   terminal
2. Restart computer without conserving the opened windows

Comment: For me, simply restarting the computer does the trick.  What I am looking for is a command line way to do it without having to restart the entire machine.

Answer (score 2):

On BigSur you can simply do,

1. Hold down the **Shift** and **Option** keys, then click on the Bluetooth icon in the menubar. If its not there then add by going to **System Preferences** > **Bluetooth** > Tick **Show Bluetooth in menu bar**.
2. And then choose **Reset the Bluetooth module** from the menu.

Comment: Is this option removed in Monterey 12.x? Shift+Option+click BT icon does not show a Reset option for me.

Comment: Looks like it has been removed in Monterey

Comment: It's gone in ventura as well

Comment: Confirming this appears to have been removed Ventura 13.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is losing Magic Mouse 2 from Macbook Air (Monterey 12.2). Then, I found the CPU usage of bluetoothd is high.

What I have tried is simply kill bluetoothd. And my Magic Mouse 2 reconnected as soon as I killed bluetoothd. It seems bluetoothd will restart automatically.

Comment: While this may be a solution, the OP specifically asked "from command line"

Answer (score 0):

all the variants mentioned here in this threads is not working properly, obviously series of error in the output..
I just want to put alias in bash_profile for turn off/on bluetooth service easily from terminal
Does any help for Applescript variants for it, which I can easliy triggering through bash_profile alias typing just one short alias command like blueon/blueoff ?

MBP:~ applehead$ > system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version: macOS 10.14.6 (18G9323)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 18.7.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Computer Name:  MBP_appleHead
  User Name: applehead (applehead)
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled
  Time since boot: 4 days 17:11
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/318371)