# Is using the Magic Mouse 2 & original Magic Mouse on the same Mac unsupported in High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, bluetooth, mouse

I recently upgraded my mid 2011 Mac mini to macOS High Sierra. I purchased the Magic Mouse 2 about a year ago, but really loathe the charging port on the bottom (unbelievably stupid design, but I digress). As such, I kept my old (original) Magic Mouse handy for when I needed to charge the Magic Mouse 2. I never had problems with this use case in OS X El Capitan.

However, today when I tried to use the old Magic Mouse, macOS absolutely freaked out and *neither* of the Bluetooth mice could connect. I had to use a generic Logitech USB mouse to "forget" both of them (old and new), then I could reconnect the Magic Mouse 2 after it charged.

So my question: <s>is the original Magic Mouse unsupported in macOS High Sierra?</s> (edit: it definitely *is* supported, not the issue). **Or perhaps I simply can no longer use the Magic Mouse and Magic Mouse 2 interchangeably?**

Update 1: Forgetting and re-pairing both of the the mice was a temporary fix. Nothing else worked, including rebooting.

Update 2: Issue has returned. I again had to fight macOS tooth-and-nail to get the Magic Mouse 2 paired after using the Magic Mouse!

Update 3: One thing I forgot to mention: when the Magic Mouse 2 has lost pairing (after using the Magic Mouse) and I plug it in and switch it on, the "Mouse" section of System Preferences goes absolutely berserk, rapidly alternating between the normal screen and the "looking for bluetooth mouse" screen.

Comment: After your Re-pairing,  when does this happen?  Does it only occur after an update? Or when they are both on and/or trying to/or have connected?  Do you have more than just your mice connected via bluetooth?

Comment: Do either of your mice have "Drifting" issues? Where, the cursor moves when you are not?

Comment: Neither seem to have any drifting issues.

Comment: The issue occurs after I stop using the MM1 and try to switch back to the MM2 - the Mac Mini "fights" me on this. It easily allows me to switch from the MM2 to the MM1, however.

Comment: Are you leaving both of the mice on when you switch?  If so, try turning off the MM1 and then Switching over to MM2. Lastly, does this ever cause issues when you are using just one mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1st Answer Alt. Using The Interface Answer (Credit [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894))

(Short Way)

Does the command line version from my understanding.

- Open System preferences
- Open Bluetooth Settings
- Click on Advanced
- Uncheck the 2nd Box "`Open Bluetooth Setup Assistant at startup if no mouse or trackpad is detected`"
  [image: Advanced Bluetooth Settings]

> Note: this may look different on your Mac as I am running on MBP macOS 10.14.5 Mojave

> Fun Note: To open Bluetooth Preferences directly from `Terminal` run: 
>  `open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Bluetooth.prefPane`

## 1st Answer Using Terminal/Commandline

My hypothesis, is I believe the bluetooth devices may be fighting.

If you don't mind a little terminal action, then, lets try turning off the Automatic Search for bluetooth.

Open `Terminal` and run:  Update 2:*This is not a mandatory step* this will show up if you run **After** the write steps.

```
defaults find 'AutoSeek'
```

This for me just returned:

```
Found 1 keys in domain 'com.apple.systempreferences': {
    BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice = 1;
}
```

So, I ran:

```
defaults read com.apple.systempreferences BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice
```

This should return 1, as it does on my machine. So, let's turn this off.

```
defaults write com.apple.systempreferences BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice -bool false
```

Doing some more research, I also found something similar, in other plist files.

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice
```

But to change this is requires your admin password as it is part of the SIP protection.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice -bool false
```

Then, to make the changes take effect: (Thanks to [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) for the update from the comments.)

```
killall cfprefsd
```

> Note: You may not have `com.apple.systempreferences` the alternative is `com.apple.systempref.plist` So if you run the `defaults read` and get an error please try the substitute.

## 3rd Answer

[Try using `blueutil` and let me know.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310732/55628)

## 4th Answer

Try ["Reseting the System Management Controller (SMC) on your Mac."](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Comment: Thank you, @JayRizzo! Unfortunately I struck out on step one (I did try the command as both root and my normal user, and from ~ and / directories): `MacMini:~ StndrdUser$ defaults find 'AutoSeek'
2019-06-24 18:05:32.891 defaults[89014:5450612] No domain, key, nor value containing 'AutoSeek'`

Comment: Thats ok, that just means that there has not been a set value "Set".   I have been going thru the PLIST files and alot of the not obvious "Options" are not set in the plist files until you run a `defaults write` call on the terminal.

Comment: Ok cool - I do have a `com.apple.systempref.plist` file...

Comment: I updated my answer to showcase that the `defaults find` is optional.   I hope that works for you.  As I am not sure if the mice are fighting over the bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks again. I have added both `0` values as described, the first is now showing, the `0` in `com.apple.Bluetooth` is not yet detected, but I'm going to reboot and check again (I assume that is will after the reboot, as you said). :)

Comment: The _value_ for `BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice` is a _boolean_ not an _integer_. - "-bool[ean]  Allows the user to specify a boolean as the value for the given preference key.  Value must be TRUE, FALSE, YES, or NO." - You also can just uncheck **[] Open Bluetooth Setup Assistant at startup if no mouse or trackpad is detected** In System Preferences > Bluetooth > Advanced instead of using `defaults`. See: https://imgur.com/a/nYTNanI

Comment: Thanks for the updates @user343894 I kind of figured as much but the problem was when you do `defaults read` you actually end up getting back only the integer value so I was working on the idea is that they were interchangeable.

Comment: Much thanks, @user3439894, I have unchecked the Bluetooth advanced option now. Also, the issue seems to be fixed now, I believe from the terminal edits to the PLIST files. :)

Comment: Weirdly enough, the bool for `defaults read com.apple.Bluetooth BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice` still doesn't exist after a reboot...but I seem to be able to switch between the MM1 and MM2 (and vice-versa) so I'm calling it fixed!

Comment: That is probably due to Mac's SIP.  You might have to disable SIP, the make the change, then, turn SIP back on. But I am glad you are all set.  Have a great one!

Comment: SIP has nothing to do with this!

Comment: Ok well it is for me, as modifying anything in '/Library/...' Is part of SIP.  But it is a mute point since the problem has been solved. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

Comment: The `plist` file that gets modified in this case is `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist`, it's not subject to SIP, and you need to run `killall cfprefsd` directly after `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice -bool false` for it to update the User's System Preferences. The easiest thing to do is just uncheck **[] Open Bluetooth Setup Assistant at startup if no mouse or trackpad is detected** In System Preferences > Bluetooth > Advanced instead of using `defaults` as it updates the system almost immediately.

Comment: BTW If you do not run run `killall cfprefsd` in this use case and instead reboot, the setting you've tried to set is overwrtten by what's already previously in memory and why unchecking the previously mentioned setting from the GUI is really the way to go here.

Comment: Also, you said, "But to change this is requires your admin password as it is part of the SIP protection." and `/Library/Preferences/` **is not** protected by SIP. It's _owned_ by `root` and why you need to use `sudo` to change a _key_ in a _plist file_ using `defaults in that location. Using the GUI sets the `BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice` _key_ in both `com.apple.Bluetooth` _plist files_.

Comment: Fair enough, I was wrong as I had misread the docs.   Thanks for the clarification.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Again @user3439894 I updated the answer to include your simplified way and added your note about the `cfprefsd`.  I just like the terminal way of doing things as it makes it easier to migrate to a new mac or re-setup my profile.  Please have a look and and adjust as needed.  @KidACrimson Glad you are all sorted. Cheers all!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any Apple documentation stating that the original Magic Mouse is unsupported in newer OS versions.

Your problem is more likely to be just one of Bluetooth connectivity. Apple provides a [troubleshooting document](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204621) that describes the Magic Mouse and Magic Mouse 2 together. Other remedies for problems can be [found here](https://mackeeper.com/blog/post/331-magic-mouse-problems-and-fixes).

The Magic Mouse is not one of Apple's strongest designs, and you may prefer a third-party mouse, or the Magic Trackpad, which I find much better. (You can leave it plugged in while using it, for starters!)

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I've seen the that Apple troubleshooting doc, but it's useless in my situation, unfortunately. I've tried all the obvious things multiple times. Despite the bottom charging-port, I actually strongly prefer the Magic Mouse over any other mouse or trackpad, (I would even use it on my Windows machines if I could) which is why this is so frustrating to me.

Comment: I can't use two Bluetooth mice of any kind simultaneously.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy That sounds like a different problem, so you should start your own question. However, I'd say having two Bluetooth mice at the same time is likely to cause problems. Do you really use two mice at the same time?

Comment: @benwiggy Not a question, I'm agreeing with you—there just isn't enough bluetooth bandwidth for two mice, I think that's what OP is describing.

Comment: I can use both the MM1 and the MM2 simultaneously after the issue is fixed, but it keeps recurring is the thing.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy, RE: "there just isn't enough bluetooth bandwidth for two mice", I have a Magic Mouse, Magic Trackpad and a Magic Keyboard all using Bluetooth and  connected at the same time to a MacBook Pro in Clamshell Mode, and have no issues, so I don't necessarily agree with the statement "there just isn't enough bluetooth bandwidth for two mice".

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to support.  I can't find any apple documents that says no.  At the same time, i have both apple mouses, and it works with high serria.  Hope this helps.